# how to find default SMTP server name?

Tags: python, smtp

I have a python script which uses `smtplib` to send out an email. I am not sure what to use for mail server name in the `smtplib.SMTP` initialization.

On my test server I use the below and it works fine.

```
...
server = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
server.sendmail( sender, to_addrs, msg.as_string() ) #msg is a MIMEText object
server.quit()
```

In the actual deployment, mail is setup more explicitly and the name that works is of the form `smtp.a-domain-name`. As an example, "smtp.mycompany.net". Temporarily I have added a parameter to my script and am now looking for a generic fix.

Is there a way to find out at run time what is the mail server name? Perhaps a Linux command that will return this name, or some readable system file that keeps track of it. (how does Linux `mail` command figure it out?)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The `mail` command uses `/usr/lib/sendmail`, which is basically the same as using `localhost`.

Comment: @jordanm thanks! I created an application-specific env var, and then also modified `mail` invokes to include `-S smtp=${MYAPP_MAIL_SERVER:-localhost}`